# FFT on vector of vectors

Tags: c++, fft

I am trying to apply an FFT on 2 sets of data. They are organized in vectors of vectors

```
 std::vector<std::vector<double>> template_data;
```

I did look into it but I can not manage to clarify if the FFT of the template_data is the equivalent of the FFT applied on each sub-vector.

Comment: From the question its unclear how your data actually is organised. Spontaneously I'd assume the vector of vector represents a single matrix, but on the other hand each vector might represent an entire matrix on its own (with cell access as `v[rowIndex * columnCount + columnIndex]`) – so which one is it?

Comment: Using a std::vector of std::vector for FFT is not a good start because the data will not be (guaranteed to be) contiguous in memory which can slow down the whole calculation of the transform (thus defeating the first F of FFT). Better to handle specific cases that have sizes of (2^n)x(2^n) and use contiguous memory for those sizes (e.g. std::array)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. The vector of vector represents a single matrix.

Comment: It was clear enough. But FFT requires some preconditions which std::vector<std::vector<double>> just will not meet. Such as guaranteed 2^n size. In any case use a (hardware accelerated) library for FFT and make sure you provide the data as the library requires.

Comment: The cost of copying your data to/from a more appropriate data structure will be relatively small compared to the cost of the FFT itself, so that's probably what you will need to do (assuming you don't have any control over the format of your data).

Comment: You should never use `std::vector<std::vector<>>` for a matrix. Use a contiguous block of memory instead. There are many good libraries out there that you could use to represent a matrix or an image or whatever you are working with. Don't roll your own if you don't need to.